# What genre is best for a song about shoes?

Tags: band-stars

I have a challenge that asks me to write a song about shoes using the most appropriate genre. Problem is, I have no idea what that is!

What's the best genre for a song about shoes?

Comment: whatever [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCF3ywukQYA) is.

Comment: Shoegaze is surely the most relevant musical genre here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hip Hop. About your sweet kicks or something like that.

Comment: That worked! Matched perfectly, got my green smiley face and song bonus. :D